# Take the last occurrence of a string value based on the latest date

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

There are 3 columns, say: Item, Item type and Sales. Now item type keeps changing frequently. Sometimes an item (say, Apple) might have item type as one thing on a particular date ("Healthy" on Jan 1) but might have something else on another date ("Vegan" on Jan 5). There are more than 500 such items.

Eg dataframe:

| Item | Item type | Date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Healthy | Jan 1 | 10 |
| Apple | Vegan | Jan 5 | 5 |

The output needs to be:

| Item | Item type | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Vegan | 15 |

(assuming Vegan is the last entry in the data) and the cumulative total sales is 15.

Now if on Jan 7 another entry is made (Apple, Fruit, 2) for Item, item type, sales, the output changes to:
Eg dataframe:

| Item | Item type | Date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Healthy | Jan 1 | 10 |
| Apple | Vegan | Jan 5 | 5 |
| Apple | Fruit | Jan 7 | 2 |

The required output:

| Item | Item type | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit | 17 |

I tried using the `df.groupby` `.last` function but it's only applicable on numerical data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The groupby last function should work in this use case, as long as you can confirm that your data is being entered chronologically you can just do

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['item', 'type', 'date', 'sales'])
df.loc[0] = ["Apple", "unripe", "Jan 1", 10]
df.loc[1] = ["Apple", "ripe", "Jan 10", 5]
df.loc[2] = ["Orange", "ripe", "Jan 12", 6]
df.groupby(["item"]).agg({'type': 'last', 'date': 'last', 'sales': sum})
```

That groupby ensures that the latest entries of date and type are used while sales is the sum of all the grouped entries.

The output looks like

```
        type    date    sales
item            
Apple   ripe    Jan 10  15
Orange  ripe    Jan 12  6
```